# remove a domain value from d3 ordinal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 ordinal scale to define a mapping:

```
d3.scale.ordinal().range(["outputa", "outputb", "outputc", ]).domain(["inputa", "inputb", "inputc"]);
```

Is there anyway I could remove a particular domain (e.g. "inputb") from the ordinal hence releasing the corresponding range element("outputb") while keeping the other mapping unchanged? ("inputa" still maps to "outputa" etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the domain/range and modify it directly:

```
var domain = scale.domain(),
    range = scale.range();

var indexToRemove = // use index directly or find in either array
domain.slice(indexToRemove, indexToRemove+1);
range.slice(indexToRemove, indexToRemove+1);

scale.domain(domain);
scale.range(range);
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I guess there is no easier way within scale/ordinal itself to achieve the same?